# iPhone detected but "could not be identified properly"

Tags: iphone

I receive this message when I connect my iPhone to my PC:

> An iPhone has been detected but it could not be identified properly. Please disconnect and reconnect the iPhone, then try again.

When I disconnect and reconnect, the message reappears.

Comment: Did you try with a different cable?

Comment: yes, i just disconnected and reconnected with a different cable with same message results, repeating

Comment: Did it work sometime before? What happened to the iPhone since?

Comment: i believe the connection from my iphone worked sometime before, connecting to a different pc. The iphone is damaged and before replacing i wished to make a successful backup directly to this current pc.

Comment: What's the iPhone model, iOS version, Windows version & iTunes version?

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting steps I would recommend (in order).

If you have access to another IOS Device with the same IOS firmware or higher, see if the PC can connect to that. If it can't connect to another device try the following:

1. Ensure you have the latest version of iTunes.
2. Try a different USB port, a different cable.
3. Completely remove iTunes and try again with a fresh copy:
   https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204275
4. If none of that works I would recommend backing up with another computer and then transferring your backup over if you wish to store the backup on the PC that isn't recognizing the iPhone.

If it does connect to another device on the same IOS version or higher.. Try the following:
1. Evaluate if the iPhone has a damaged cable. Most iPhones (all iPhone 5 & up) have the ribbon cable running from the lighting port around the bottom right corner. If you have a damaged screen in that area chances could be that [cable][1] is damaged. You may need a new charging port assembly.
2. Confirm that the lighting port is clean, blow it out with compressed air or carefully remove any debris that may be inside.

If you don't have another device to try, following the steps from the first part, then followed by the second.

Without knowing what type of damage specifically happened to the iPhone, I would hope that you would find a solution with the above steps. If you believe the cable could be damaged, that would be a logical issue. Reply if clarification is needed.

Good luck!